# Error in model.frame.default(object, data, xlev = xlev) : object is not a matrix

Tags: r, glmnet, model.matrix

3 days old to R and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I'm trying to send some columns with two way interactions into a glmnet cox model.  I have some data.frame() called dtable

*Edit to make the code reproducible*

```
xs<-c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3")
v<-c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, NA, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, NA, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30)
df<-data.frame(matrix(v,ncol=3))
dm<-as.matrix(df)
dm<-matrix(dm[complete.cases(dm)], ncol=3)
colnames(dm)<-xs
dfdata<-data.frame(dm)
f<-as.formula(time~.*.)
xmatrix<-model.matrix(f, dfdata)[,-1]
```

When I run this I get the error

```
Error in model.frame.default(object, data, xlev = xlev) :    
object is not a matrix
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of the formula: time~.*.
In the data.frame() there is no time column for the formula to cross everything by.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of this:

```
dm<-matrix(dm[complete.cases(dm)], ncol=3)
```

you want this:

```
dm <- as.matrix(dm[complete.cases(dm), ])
```

Not to toot my own horn (too much), but consider using [glmnetUtils](https://github.com/hong-revo/glmnetUtils) to simplify the task of managing data frames, formulas and model matrices.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.  as far as the as.matrix() I get no love.

Answer (score -2):

I suspect the error is telling exactly what is wrong. The object you are passing to `model.matrix()` is not a matrix. What is the result of `class(data)`? Probably a data.frame.

Try adding `as.matrix()` to the `model.matrix()` call to `data`.

Two other notes - don't call your data.frames `data`. Also asks questions here using a reproducible example. You'll get better responses.

Comment: nope, model.matrix() requires a data.frame() for the second term.  Noted on the other two things though.