# R Error in model.frame.default: object is not a matrix when using lm

Tags: r, loops, matrix, formula, lm

For reproducible example:

```r
test <- structure(list(IDcount = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), year = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Otminus1 = c(-0.28, -0.28, -0.44, 
-0.27, 0.23, -0.03, -0.06, -0.04, 0, 0.02), N.1 = c(NA, -0.1, 
0.01, 0.1, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.05, -0.05), N.2 = c(NA, 
NA, -0.09, 0.11, 0.06, NA, -0.08, -0.08, -0.09, -0.09), N.3 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 0.01, 0.07, NA, NA, -0.12, -0.13, -0.13), N.4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, -0.04, NA, NA, NA, -0.05, -0.05), N.5 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.13)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
    IDcount = c(1, 2), .rows = structure(list(1:5, 6:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

results <- structure(list(IDcount = c(1, 2), N.1 = c(NA, NA), N.2 = c(NA, 
NA), N.3 = c(NA, NA), N.4 = c(NA, NA), N.5 = c(NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm performing a `lm` regression without intercept over the `data frame` "test" in a nested for loop and writing coefficients into "results" using this code:

```r
index <- colnames(test) %>% str_which("N.")

betas <- matrix(nrow=length(unique(test$IDcount)), ncol=2)
colnames(betas) <- c("Intercept", "beta")

for (j in colnames(test)[index]) {
  for (i in 1:2) {
    tmp <- test[test$IDcount==i, c("Otminus1", j)]
    if(any(colSums(!is.na(tmp)) == 0)) next
    betas[i,] <- coef(lm(Otminus1 ~ . -1, tmp))
  }
  betas <- data.frame(betas)
  results[[j]] <- betas$beta
}
```

This works perfectly. But I would now like to switch out the y and x variable so that the formula in the loop reads:

```r
betas[i,] <- coef(lm(. ~ Otminus1 -1, tmp))
```

But when doing so I receive the following error message:

```r
Error in model.frame.default(formula = . ~ Otminus1 - 1, data = tmp, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) :   
Object is not a matrix
```

I tried to consider this by introducing `as.matrix`:

```r
betas[i,] <- coef(lm(. ~ Otminus1 -1, as.matrix(tmp)))
```

But when doing this I receive this error:

```r
Error in model.frame.default(formula = . ~ Otminus1 - 1, data = as.matrix(tmp), : 
 'data' must be a data frame not matrix or an array
```

I found [Error in model.frame.default(object, data, xlev = xlev) : object is not a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682261/error-in-model-frame-defaultobject-data-xlev-xlev-object-is-not-a-matrix) but I haven't been able to apply this to my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot `.` only works for the RHS of a formula. The reason is probably the ambiguity that appears, if there are more than two columns in the data set (contrary to your special case). You could use `reformulate` instead, which helps to create a formula for using in `lm`.

```
for (j in colnames(test)[index]) {
  for (i in 1:2) {
    tmp <- test[test$IDcount == i, c("Otminus1", j)]
    if(any(colSums(!is.na(tmp)) == 0)) 
      betas[i, ] <- NA
    else {
      fo <- reformulate(names(tmp)[1], names(tmp)[2], intercept=FALSE)
      betas[i,] <- coef(lm(fo, tmp))
    }
  }
  betas <- data.frame(betas)
  results[[j]] <- betas$beta
}

results
#   IDcount         N.1        N.2       N.3       N.4  N.5
# 1       1 -0.03167421 0.07420163 0.1065183 -0.173913   NA
# 2       2  0.64615385 1.10714286 1.1000000 -2.500000 -6.5
```

#### Alternative solution w/o `for` loop

Here a more R-like way without using `for` loops. First, we create the two needed vectors for the independent variables and the IDcounts. Using `outer` we `paste` possible combinations separated by a `,`,

```
i.vars <- grep("N.", names(test), value=TRUE)
n.IDcount <- 1:2
combs <- outer(i.vars, n.IDcount, paste, sep=",")
```

giving this matrix.

```
combs
#         [,1]    [,2]   
# [1,] "N.1,1" "N.1,2"
# [2,] "N.2,1" "N.2,2"
# [3,] "N.3,1" "N.3,2"
# [4,] "N.4,1" "N.4,2"
# [5,] "N.5,1" "N.5,2"
```

Now we loop via `sapply` through `combs`, make a `strsplit` at the `,`, use the first value as IV, and the second value to subset `test` data. Impossible iterations would yield an error (the `N.5` case with `IDcount == 1`), so we use `tryCatch` and let the code throw `NA` in such case.

```
res <- sapply(combs, function(v) {
  x <- el(strsplit(v, ","))
  tmp <- test[test$IDcount == x[2], ]
  tryCatch(lm(as.formula(paste0(x[1], "~ Otminus1 - 1")), tmp)$coe,
           error=function(e) NA)
})
```

Finally we put the `res`ult into a matrix.

```
matrix(res, 2, byrow=TRUE, dimnames=list(n.IDcount, i.vars))
#           N.1        N.2       N.3       N.4  N.5
# 1 -0.03167421 0.07420163 0.1065183 -0.173913   NA
# 2  0.64615385 1.10714286 1.1000000 -2.500000 -6.5
```

Comment: The code went through, but unfortunately, the results are identical to before switching the x and y variables. This code therefore still seems to regress ```lm(Otminus ~ . -1, tmp)```

Comment: @ConnorUhl Seems I've interchanged x and y, could you try now please?

Comment: I've come unto a new problem. When running the code results are written into the field of N.5 with the IDcount 1 although there are no observations to run the regression. In my previous version, the for loop would write in "NA" if no regression is possible. Instead, the code is now copying in the value of the previous regression (columns N.4, IDcount 1). Any Idea how to amend this?

Comment: @ConnorUhl I see, let me think about it one minute.

Comment: @ConnorUhl Just set teh value to `NA` instead of using `next`, see editet version.

Comment: @ConnorUhl Welcome, also see alternative solution w/o `for` loop.